# HTTP POST request health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Amazon's ELB does an `HTTP GET` request to check the health of a server. Is it possible to configure this to use `POST` instead? If so, how would that be done?

Comment: Why? Using a post to request information doesn't make sense as an HTTP verb

Comment: The endpoint that I want to check on only receives (and processes) data in a `POST` call. It's not a normal web endpoint.

Comment: A POST call should be creating some resource. If you had a load balancer pinging it every few seconds or minutes you'd have a huge problem. Can you modify the web service end point to create a `/status?` end point that you call with a GET? This would be how you would do this typically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You could set up a GET route that makes a POST request to yourself and returns the response, but you can't make ELB do a POST